# Dockerized Flask application partly loading pictures

Tags: python, docker, flask

I currently have a Docker container running with a Flask app. This Flask app is running a simple website that uses images. These images are loaded via the flask typical static folder.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', static_url_path='/')
```

But when this page is called while running in the container, images sometimes take forever to load for no apparent reason. They are displayed on the web page, but the loading icon does not disappear and when you cancel the loading, the image disappears and the "alt" text appears.

Even converting the images to WebP didn't help.
The Flask server is running with an SSL certificate (could be an important information).

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=443, ssl_context=('fullchain.pem', 'privkey.pem'))
```

The pictures are implemented in HTML with:

```
<img src="/picture.webp" alt="picture">
```

My Dockerfile looks like that:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /
COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

And my requirements.txt:
`flask`

Buliding the docker with:
`docker build /path/to/dockerfile -t app`

and running:
`docker run -d -p 443:443 --restart=always app`

I hope some of you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the browser console?

Comment: @JakobF yes nothing - and in DevTools the picture is "pending". But is clearly visible on the website. (Maybe just cached)

Comment: Often issues like this are caused by your paths being different in your container vs local machine. Try running your container to spawn a shell and looking at the directory structure and ensure your `static` directory is where you think it is. Also check the logs in the container to see why flask isn't serving these images as you would expect.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for your advice! Checked the logs: HTML codes (response) are always either 200 or 304 for the images. The static folder path is right, checked it with ```docker exec -t -i container /bin/bash```